# When I integrate Paytm payment gateway I get an 'Oops' screen

Tags: android, paytm

When I click on button for payment I am getting this screen in Paytm payment gateway integration.

"The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://pguat.paytm.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source:  (0)
10-12 10:32:53.425 28178-28178/simplifiedcoding.net.paytmpaymentsample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://pguat.paytm.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction?ORDER_ID=5e276d747c494e9c9ad0d96d0d9bc0d9 (0)
10-12 10:32:53.487 28178-28178/simplifiedcoding.net.paytmpaymentsample D/PGSDK: Page finished loading https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction?ORDER_ID=5e276d747c494e9c9ad0d96d0d9bc0d9
    Progress dialog ended

```
MID = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CALLBACK_URL = https://staging-dashboard.paytm.com/
TXN_AMOUNT = 10.00
ORDER_ID = 5e276d747c494e9c9ad0d96d0d9bc0d9
WEBSITE = APPSTAGING
INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = Retail
CHECKSUMHASH = RcB5jdzu2By+umW9oMoYiAuEITbFeG0M5boxSD7HrxX4/N4UnYcVTkGXtQA5w1L4GTadVLeyIK8EWDWaJreHVagwVm5byoUs5ZL1CMLRC5w=
CHANNEL_ID = WAP
CUST_ID = c9cd91cb4c4e4376abdf40282c14980c
```

[image: click for error image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vYmr.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Have a think about whether it's remotely possible for anyone to help you with this given the information you have provided (i.e., a generic error message and nothing else at all). We need your relevant source code, any relevant logs, and anything else that may help people zero in on the root cause. Thanks.

Comment: Is your call back URL working? Are you generating checksum properly? Passing WEBSITE as APP_STAGING in your code?

Comment: paramMap.put("MID", "APTAPS93665250396544");

paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", paytm.getOrderId());

paramMap.put("CUST_ID", "9499292329");

paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");

paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1.0");

paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "APP_STAGING");

paramMap.put("CALLBACK_URL", "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback");

paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH", checksumHash);

paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");

Comment: can you please check this

Comment: {
CHECKSUMHASH: "k9ftYkI5CI8ZetEEpZtYAjjp/abfj/rTA4N8U7F4fudHR/hjz3S8nBD35YKRzJQUMcf+bzIuK7kyBVDGU5UWD0KdnERC1wtyyvXVUBalv8U=",
ORDER_ID: null,
payt_STATUS: "1"
}

Comment: Can you post your log exception?. I mean please post your exception you are getting.

Comment: Whatever you have posted isn't sufficient for us to understand the type of error

Comment: i have edited my post. can you please check onec

Answer (score 0):

Just run the application in the emulator and in LOGCAT check for error in each step. You can then easily figure out what the main problem is.
Sometimes, one can forget to mention the activity in the manifest file, so you can check your manifest file.